# mongodb - require authentication on database basis?

Tags: authentication, mongodb

Is it possible to require authentication only on specific mongodb databases (leaving other databases with free access with no authentication requirements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. According to the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/):

> Enabling access control on a MongoDB deployment enforces authentication, requiring users to identify themselves.

So authentication, when enabled, is enabled on the mongodb instance, so you can't have databases within the instance not requiring authentication.